# update array in mongodb with new item and value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update the array: ['media_details'] with a local image path after the image has been downloaded. However using $push just added the local_url on top.

This is what ['media_details'] looks like:

```
"image_details": [
    {
      "processed": true,
      "position": 0,
      "seconds": "46",
      "src_url": "https://xxxxx/1.jpg",
      "image_fname": "1.jpg",
    },
    {
      "processed": true,
      "position": 1,
      "seconds": "55",
      "src_url": "https://xxxxx/2.jpg",
      "image_fname": "2.jpg",
    },
```

my code then downloads the image from the src_url and I want to add the local image url to the ['media_details'].

```
job = mongo.db.JobProcess
job.update({'_id': db_id},
                   {'$push': {
                       'image_details': {
                           'local_url': img_local_file,

                       }
                   }})
```

This adds the local_url to the top of the ['media_details'] - like so:

```
{'local_url': '/bin/static/5432ec0f-ea53-4fe1-83e4-f78166d1b9a6/1.jpg'}, 
{'local_url': '/bin/static/5432ec0f-ea53-4fe1-83e4-f78166d1b9a6/2.jpg'}, 
{'processed': True, 'position': 0, 'seconds': '46', 'src_url': 'https://xxxxx1.jpg', 'image_fname': '1.jpg'}
```

what I want it to do is:

```
 "image_details": [
        {
          "processed": true,
          "position": 0,
          "seconds": "46",
          "src_url": "https://xxxxx/1.jpg",
          "image_fname": "1.jpg",
          "local_url": "/bin/static/5432ec0f-ea53-4fe1-83e4-f78166d1b9a6/1.jpg"
        },
```

but which command ($set, $push, $addToSet) is best suited for updating this? and how do I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the image_details array item using the positional operator $. You will need a query that can uniquely identify the array item, perhaps src_url:

```
job.update({$and:[ 
                  {"_id": db_id},                              
                  {"image_details.src_url": img_src_url }
                  ]},
           {$set :{"image_details.$.local_url": img_local_file },
           {multi:false})
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I use a combination of both answers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [positional update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
job.updateOne({
  '_id': db_id,
  'image_details.src_url': yourUrl,
}, {
  $set: {
    'image_details.$.local_url': img_local_file
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I use a combination of both answers! - but I can only give one tick.